# Defining Functions for Geany "Filetype"

Tags: geany, snakemake

I am using Geany as my text editor. I have started working on [snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/wiki/Home), which, from a syntax point-of-view, is Python with a few modifications. Python functions are defined by:

```
def bla:
    bunch_of_code
```

snakemake adds the definition of "rules" in a similar way:

```
rule bla:
    bunch_of_code
```

Geany presents in the side bar all the Python functions, but I also want it to present all the rules. However, I was not able to find how to define the keywords for a function in the file geany/filetypes.python (I want to add the keyword `rule`).

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: The symbol browser — I guess you are referring too — ist not based upon filetypes.python-file, but on C code you might have to patch for archiving this goal. A good starting point would be documentation http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html#adding-a-filetype